# Get first instances of a subclass from a list using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two subclasses of a class. Now I have a list that can contain either of the subclasses.

Now I need to iterate through the list and get the first occurrence of Subclass B.

I have used the below and looking for Java 8/stream/lambda way of doing this.

```
SeniorEmployee sEmp = null;    
for(Employee emp: empList){
if(emp instanceof SeniorEmployee)
 sEmp = emp;
 break;
}
```

Comment: Aside: improper braces wouldn't let this compile

Comment: If *there is no senior employee in the list* is a non-exceptional situation, which it is in my opinion, it would be better to return an `Optional<SeniorEmployee>` rather than a `SeniorEmployee`. It'll probably save you a bunch of null-checks or NPE's in the future.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
SeniorEmployee sEmp = emp.stream()
                         .filter(SeniorEmployee.class::isInstance)
                         .findFirst()
                         .map(SeniorEmployee.class::cast)
                         .orElse(null);
```

Where you can put in some other default value in the `orElse` section. This solution uses [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) to get the first element that matches the `Predicate`

Also note that `orElse(null)` is to make the code equivalent to the code in the question. It is best to give a value other than `null`, as that defeats the entire purpose of the `Optional`

Comment: `orElse(null)` to match to the imperative style in the question.

Comment: Nitpick: `filter(SeniorEmployee.class::isInstance)` would be better because it would not create an additional inner class for a lambda.

Comment: @VGR that’s mostly a matter of style, so it should be consistent, i.e. either `.filter(SeniorEmployee.class::isInstance) .map(SeniorEmployee.class::cast)` or `.filter(x -> x instanceof SeniorEmployee) .map(x -> (SeniorEmployee)x)`. If it is about the tiniest bit of performance, it might be surprising, but with current implementations, the lambda expressions are more efficient here, as they are non-capturing, hence, can be re-used. There will be no “inner class” for a lambda, but a runtime-generated anonymous class, not different to method references.

Comment: I'm not a fan of using `orElse(null)`, it really is against the usage of `Optional` objects. Why not use `sEmp.isPresent()` later in the process instead of again having a ol' bad null check

Comment: @YassinHajaj Yes that was simply to make it the equivalent of the OP's code